# Galaxy W bricked?

Tags: unbricking

I tried to upgrade the android version of my Galaxy W but ended up bricking up my phone.

- Recovery mode - not working
- Download mode - working
- USB - not working (PC doesn't recognise my phone)
- Tried odin - doesn't detect the phone

Please help!!!

Comment: Sounds like a soft brick. Please mention the version you were upgrading from and the one to. Is this an official update which bricked your phone?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Sammy devices; but as long as Download mode still works, isn't it that Odin/[Heimdall](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/heimdall/info) can push things to flash? How to tweak the driver so Odin does find the device in that mode?

Comment: I tried to upgrade from 2.3.6 to official release of 4.2  from samsung kies